# Method is called multiple times but called only once

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I implemented Facebook SDK in my Android application. I am using the login function of the SDK. What i am trying to do is the following :

- When MainActivity starts, check if there is an active session
- If there isn't, give the user the chance to login into facebook
- If there is, user has to be redirected to an other Activity (let's call this : HomeActivity).

When my application starts, it starts the MainActivity. My `onCreate()` method looks like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  this.app = (ApplicationClass)getApplicationContext();

  app.setUiHelper(new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback));

  uiHelper = app.getUiHelper();
  uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if(this.app.getLoggedIn()) {

      setContentView(R.layout.login);
  startLoggingIn(); // <-- Makes login button invisible and starts spinner
      login();


  } else {

      setContentView(R.layout.login);

  }
}
```

`ApplicationClass` is a class where i set all kind of information that can be used throughout the application lifecycle. It doesn't really matter but i thought i include it in the example.

So when MainActivity starts, it should call `login()` method, which looks like this :

```
public void login() {

            logging_in = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "Loggin in");
            synchronized (this) {

                  // start Facebook Login
                  Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    // callback when session changes state
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {


                        if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {

                            // make request to the /me API
                            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                              // callback after Graph API response with user object
                              @Override
                              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                                  if (user != null) { // User is logged in

                                      app.setUser(user);
                                      app.setLoggedIn(true);

                                      // Redirect user to the HomeActivity
                                      Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                                      startActivity(intent);

                                  } 
                              }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                  });

                  logging_in = false;

            }


    }
```

And finally, my callback for Facebook session looks like this :

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            synchronized (this) {
                  if( ! logging_in ) {
                      login();  
                  }

            }


        } else if (state.isClosed()) {

            setContentView(R.layout.login);

        }
    }
```

It does it all well, except the `login()` method gets called about many times. The output in my log is :

[image]

Why does it get called so many times? It obviously make sure the `HomeActivity` intent is started multiple times. I can't figure out why.

**Solution**

Changed my Session.StateCallback a little bit. It now looks like this :

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            if(state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {

                Log.i(TAG, "OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED");
                login();

            } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED) {

                if(app.getUser() != null) {

                    // Redirect user to the HomeActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {

                    login();

                }

            }


        } else if (state.isClosed()) {

            if(state == SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED");

                setContentView(R.layout.login);

            } else if(state == SessionState.CLOSED) {

                Log.i(TAG, "CLOSED");
                //setContentView(R.layout.login);
            }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most likely because you're calling login from onSessionState changed.

When you login what do think is going to happen to the session, it's going to change right.
And when it changes it calls onSessionState change and you call login.

I would expect that to loop infinitely but it seems Facebook have done some handling for this.

Comment: Thanks. I am now redirecting to the next Activity when state == SessionState.OPENED. I will accept your answer because you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem .. I just changed my activity result code . And it worked ..